# JQuery ajax don't invoke remote page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have this code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <?php
        session_start();
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['modepayment']) && $_REQUEST['modepayment'] == 'success') {
            ?>



            <script>
                alert('alborz1');
                var user1 = "<?= $_SESSION['user'] ?>";
                var no_sms1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['n_m']; ?>",
                var mail1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>",
                var monto1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['monto']; ?>",
                var refe1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['refe']; ?>",
                var tipo_tar1 = "";
                var valueKeys = {tipo_tar:tipo_tar1, monto:monto1, n_m = no_sms1, refe:refe1, usuario:user1, email:mail1};
                $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "insertar.php", data: valueKeys,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        <?php
                        $_SESSION['n_m'] = '';
                        $_SESSION['email'] = '';
                        $_SESSION['monto'] = '';
                        $_SESSION['refe'] = '';
                        ?>
                        if (data.indexOf("SMS") >= 0) {
                            $(".centro").hide();
                            $(".content-area").hide();
                            $("#bodythxRecarga").show();
                        }
                    }
                });


            </script>




            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>alert('alborz');</script>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I browse the page with payment.php?modepayment=success, only first alert is executed and ajax invoke didn't execute. I try all correction to ajax and array definition but nothing happen. inserar.php is exist and work properly but this ajax method didn't work. I use firebug and didn't see any ajax invokation.

Comment: you must put your  `session_start()` at the top your code

Comment: `console.log(valueKeys);`

Comment: Also, you realize that the php code in your success callback will be executed before the initial page is even sent to the browser, right? What is the significance of putting it there rather than somewhere else?

Comment: for example where I put them?

Answer (score 0):

You are only seeing one `alert()` and assuming your AJAX call is failing but in fact, it is succeeding.  But by manually going to that page, you don't send any POST data for it to test against this:

```
if(data.indexOf("SMS")>=0){
```

and therefore you don't get the benefit of the rest of the code inside of it.

Comment: You need to have the function get `data` from another page, not from itself.  Saying `data.indexOf...` in that spot is telling AJAX to take whatever it RECEIVED from the PHP page that was just requested and use it as `data`.  It's not referring to `valueKeys`